# SCHEME - How to write a loop that reads a value from a text file and assign it to a variable

Tags: scheme

I have a text file which contains 100 columns and 1095 rows. I need to write a scheme code to read one row of my txt file in each loop and assign each of 100 numbers in the raw to 100 different variables, and this repeats 1095 time.

These are what I have in-hand now:

***A.*** This is the code that I used for assigning values to variables and I read it through ANSYS-FLUENT (computational fluid dynamic tool).

```
(define flow-wt-1 0.0)
 (define run
 ( lambda(flow-time)
(if (< flow-time 181)
    (set! flow-wt-1 '1.0)
    (set! flow-wt-1 '0.0))
 (ti-menu-load-string (format #f "def bc outflow 6 ~a" flow-wt-1))
  )
)
```

***B.*** I have also found the code below to read a txt file.

```
(defun load_data (arr column filename)
(setf lnt (first (array-dimensions arr)))
 (with-open-file (str (format nil "~A.txt" filename) :direction :input)
   (loop :for i :from 0 :to (1- lnt) :do
       (setf (aref arr i 0) (read-from-string (nth (1- column) (split-sequence:SPLIT-SEQUENCE #\Space (read-line str)))))
    )
  )
 )
```

**Now, what I want to do is:**
 I want to remove the "if" condition (under A) and use the value of flow-time as the counter of the loop that I want to code to read each row of my txt file. 
And instead of '1.0 in (set! flow-wt-1 '1.0) I want to refer to (for example) second column of the first row.

**My question is:**
 Can I connect this two piece of code together? How can I call a value from the txt file?

I would really appreciate any suggestions and advices.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The first code is written in Scheme, the second one is in Common Lisp. They are 2 different languages.

Comment: Oh!
How can I read a text file line by line in Scheme? Is it the write form to open a text file and read on line? ((call-with-input-file "doorstate.txt"
  (lambda (flow-wt)
    (let* ((a (read flow-wt))
           (b (read flow-wt))
           (c (read flow-wt)))
    )
  )
)

Comment: So you want to make 100,000 variables. Then what?

Comment: To read a line, you can use `get-line` (R6RS) or `read-line` (R7RS) depending on which implementation you are using.

Comment: To Sylwester: Then I feed them to the software that I am using.

Comment: Just as an aside, **A** could be rewritten as `(define run
  (lambda (flow-time)
    (ti-menu-load-string (format #f "def bc outflow 6 ~a"
                                 (if (< flow-time 181) "1.0" "0.0")))))`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful (using GNU guile, details may differ):

```
(with-input-from-file
    "your/file.dat"
  (lambda ()
    (let loop ((line (read-line)))
      (if (not (eof-object? line))
          (let ((fields (string-split line #\space)))
            (display fields) ;; or whatever else you need to do
            (loop (read-line)))))))
```

Comment: Thanks Micheal Vehrs!
But how should I refer to each line later in my code?

Comment: Each line of the input file is assigned to the variable `line`. Thus, at some point within the loop, you call `(my-procedure line)`.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't assigned my input lines to the variable line.
I receive this error: 
Error: let syntax: binding is not a list
Error Object: line
I don't know if my input file (*.txt) is  the problem or using let is wrong.
I also tried let* and set and set! non of them worked.

Comment: The input file is not the problem. Without seeing your code, I cannot say what you are doing wrong. Maybe you are trying to refer to `line` outside of the loop?